# How to remove the extra padding below an one line UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I wanna to use a **UILabel** to show some words which is sent from Server，these words which i set them as **NSMutableAttributeString** sometimes **only occupy one line** (only in this case, the problem comes).

I intend to get the exact space which the label would take up,but when the label only takes up one line,and very important  — **i set the NSMutableAttributeString with lineSpacing** (10px,NSMutableParagraphStyle),but this，unexpectedly，
 would also works when even there is only one line here —  the problem  shows up as some extra padding below the word (i test with some chinese word,but attention: *if the words takes up more than one line, there is no problem*). and the weird
story is — *if the word is purely english or Arabic numerals，the extra padding won't  exist*)

the following pics may shows the problem a little clearly:

**1.English words -- oneline (*no* extra padding)**[test words:today 0987776]

### [image: Test with english words]

**2.Chinese words -- oneline (*some* extra padding)**[test words:今天天气好啊!]

### [image: Test with chinese words]

Hope someone would help .  Thx a  lot.

Comment: It would help for you to edit your question to include the mixed-language text you're trying to format, so we can try it ourselves. I can't copy the text out of a PNG to paste into a test program.

Comment: thx  a lot !   @rob mayoff

Answer (score 1):

use `sizeToFit` on a label  to the size required by the text

---

`[yourlabelName sizeToFit];`

any other `padding` would be from the font, the label itself doesn't apply any other padding

Comment: thx a lot !  this does not work..   i use this method before :     - (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext * _Nullable)context

Answer (score 0):

// baselineOffset, It was totally hit and miss   Hope to help you

[attributedString addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@(baselineOffset) range:range];